# Possible to return a String array

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, methods

Is it possible to make a method that returns a `String[]` in java?

Comment: For questions as simple as this, you're probably best off just trying first, and then posting if you get stuck.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow..You might need to first refer to the most basic tutorials flooded out there on net and then try first before even expecting any help on SO

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, but in Java the type is `String[]`, not `string[]`. The case is important.

For example a method could look something like this:

```
public String[] foo() {
    // ...
}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program program = new Program();
        String[] greeting = program.getGreeting();
        for (String word: greeting) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }

    public String[] getGreeting() {
        return new String[] { "hello", "world" };
    }
}
```

Result:

```
hello
world
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/2eM2O)

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

```
/** Returns a String array of length 5 */
public String[] createStringArray() {
    return new String[5];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes:

```
String[] dummyMethod()
{
    String[] s = new String[2];
    s[0] = "hello";
    s[1] = "world";
    return s;
}
```

Comment: The other obvious choice would have been "foo" + "bar", but then I see you managed to have a foo in your answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

yes.

```
public String[] returnStringArray()
{
    return new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
}
```

Do you have a more specific need?

Answer (score 1):

Sure

```
public String [] getSomeStrings() {
    return new String [] { "Hello", "World" };
}
```